# codeigniter call function with jquery no reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter-3

i am reading and trying to get this to work for several hours. I am pretty new with javascript and only have a small knowledge base about it in general.

I hope someone can be so kind as to help me and share their knowledge with me.

The problem:
I have a image gallery with a php generated masonry look. And a visualization of either a selected or deselected image. (Info comes out of db). Now when i click a image it needs to call a method in one of my controllers.

And afterwards update the selected to deselected or vise versa css style.

The methods have been made and the return aswell.

This is what i got so far. But nothing seems to be working. I don't know if it is something specific to codeigniter or to javascript (jquery).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('div#imagelink').click(function()
    {
        var imgId = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        $('#result').load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>selection/selectionImage/' + imgId);
        return false;
    });
});
```

If anything else is required i will be happy to provide.

```
<div class="flex-column width-1275">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="p-2">
            <h1><?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?></h1>
            <h3><?php echo str_replace( '_', ' ', $selected_gallery) . ' Galerij'; ?></h3>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('gallerymsg'); ?>
        <div class="p-2 text-right">
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('clientmsg') . '</br>'; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid imageGallery" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", columnWidth: ".grid-sizer" }'>
        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

        <?php $counter=1 ; $sizeGallery=c ount($images); foreach($images as $img) : $imageLocation='img/jpg/' . $folderName . '/' . $img[ 'image_name']; $id=$ selected_gallery . $counter; ?>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <a href="#<?php echo $id; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url($imageLocation) ?>" alt="<?php echo $selected_gallery . ' ' . $counter ?>">
                        </a>
            <?php $class='' ; $selected=$ img[ 'image_selected']; switch($selected) { case '0'; $class='isNot' ; break; case '1'; $class='is' ; break; default; $class='isNot' ; break; } if($img[ 'image_locked']=='1' ) { $class='locked' ; } ?>
            <div id="imagelink" class="<?php echo $class ?> selected">
                <?php if ($img[ 'image_locked']=='0' ) : ?>
                <!-- <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>selection/selectionImage/<?php echo $img['image_id']; ?>" class="selection-link"></a> -->
                <a href="<?php echo $img['image_id']; ?>" class="selection-link"></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cssbox">
            <a id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="#<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <img class="cssbox_thumb">
                <span class="cssbox_full">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url($imageLocation) ?>">
                        </span>
                <div class="<?php echo $class ?> Lightbox-Selected"></div>
            </a>
            <a class="cssbox_close" href="#void"></a>
            <?php if($counter < $sizeGallery) : ?>
            <?php $next=$ counter+1; ?>
            <a class="cssbox_next" href="#<?php echo $selected_gallery . $next ?>">&gt;</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($counter> 1) : ?>
            <?php $prev=$ counter-1; ?>
            <a class="cssbox_prev" href="#<?php echo $selected_gallery . $prev ?>">&lt;</a>
            <?php endif ?>
        </div>

        <?php $counter++; endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div#imagelink').click(function() {
            var imgId = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            $('#result').load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>selection/selectionImage/' + imgId);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/image-select.js'); ?>"></script> -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/masonry.pkgd.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/masonry.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of calling that function on your controller? Is it returning any data?

Comment: It is changing the value in de db to be either selected or not selected. The return value would be something to show the user it worked.

Comment: Since you are calling another method with a returning value, try to use [jQuery ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp)

Comment: Ok i tryed that aswell. But just sharing a general page is not gonna get me much further ahead. Like i said at the start of my message. I am a novice, noob when it comes to javascript.